# How to resolve problem with JsonSchemaValidator?

Tags: java, json, rest-assured, json-schema-validator

Can't use JsonSchemaValidator. Please help to resolve this error. or maybe it is library bug?
My code in test:

```
Response resp = given().cookie(cookie).when().get(getEndpointLink("link_menuItems"));
resp.then().assertThat().body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("jsonSchema.json"));
```

Dependencies:

```
compile group: 'io.rest-assured', name: 'json-schema-validator', version: '4.1.2'
compile group: 'com.github.fge', name: 'json-schema-core', version: '1.2.5'
compile group: 'com.github.fge', name: 'json-schema-validator', version: '2.2.6'
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.10.0'
compile group: 'com.github.fge', name: 'jackson-coreutils', version: '1.8'
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonSchema, but interface was expected
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are having json-schema-validator-2.2.8.jar present in your library path. In 2.2.8 version, they have converted JsonSchema class into interface.